# Proof of Drinker paradox

Tags: logic, proof-verification, quantifiers, fake-proofs, paradoxes

I searched all over the internet but didn't find a formal proof for this [paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox), so here is my attempt:

$\exists x[P(x)\implies \forall yP(y)]$

Let $x=x_0$.
Thus $P(x_0)$ is given.

Let $y$ be arbitrary. So we have to prove $P(y)$.

$y$ being arbitarary means that either $y=x_0$ or $y\ne x_0$.

So now we prove $P(x_0) \lor P(z)$ where $z$ is arbitrary and $z\ne x_0$.

$P(x_0)$ is given. So the paradox is true.
$\square$

Is this correct ? If not what is wrong ?

Comment: @gitgud So I cant really separate the conclusion to cases ?

Comment: @gitgud Doesn't separating the $y$ into 2 cases give me all the possible $y$ values ?

Comment: But you'd need to conclude $P(y)$ is both cases. This isn't what you've done.

Comment: You can find several proofs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py). I like [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py/412424#412424).

Comment: Note that $\exists x: P(x) \implies \forall x:P(x)$ is not true in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is bad. You don't have $P(x_0)$ is *given*. You have to show that such $x_0$ exists.

The point is that if there $x_0$ such that $\lnot P(x_0)$, then $P(x_0)\rightarrow\forall yP(y)$ is vacuously true; otherwise for all $x$ it is true that $P(x)$ and therefore $\forall yP(y)$ is true, and the implication is again true, in which case any choice of $x$ will prove the statement.

One key point is that the proof doesn't constructively show which of the option holds, is it the case that $\forall yP(y)$ is true, or perhaps there exists some $x$ such that $\lnot P(x)$?

Comment: I used existential instantination to get $P(x_0)$.

Comment: But the instantiation doesn't give you $P(x_0)$. It gives you $P(x_0)\rightarrow\forall yP(y)$.

Comment: @Nameless Presumably $\exists x[P(x)\implies \forall yP(y)]$ is your thesis and not a premise. You can't instantitiate (is this a word?) from your goal.

Comment: Also what @Git Gud said is very true.

Comment: Sorry I didn't instantitiate(I don't think its a word), I just Let $x=x_0$ which is what Velleman does with $\exists x P(x)$ conclusions.

Comment: @Gitgud Yeah I shouldn't have let $P(x_0)$ be given. Also can you please give me a formal proof with symbols not a worded one.

Comment: @Nameless From what I gather from a two second look at the section "To prove a goal of the form $\exists xP(x)$", he's talking about specific instances of $P$. In such a case, one way to prove this is by pinpointing an element which satisfies whatever follows the existential quantifier. But on your question you're talking about a random $P$ (in a random universe). You can't possible prove it by instantiation.

Comment: This isn't a formal proof, but I think it is what you really want: $$\begin{align}\exists x\left[P(x)\to \forall yP(y)\right]&\iff \exists x\left[\neg P(x)\lor \forall yP(y)\right]\\ &\iff \exists x\neg P(x)\lor \exists x\forall yP(y)\\ &\iff \exists x\neg P(x)\lor \forall yP(y)\\ &\iff \neg \forall x P(x)\lor \forall xP(x).\end{align}$$

Comment: @Gitgud  Can you please tell me the justification of $\exists x \forall y P(y)$ $\leftrightarrow$ $\forall x P(x)$.

Comment: Semantically, assuming the universe isn't empty (otherwise neither the initial statement, nor that equivalence are true), assume $\forall xP(x)$ is true. Since $x$ is a bounded variable, you can change it, thus getting $\forall yP(y)$. Since the universe isn't empty there exists $x$. Therefore there exists $x$ such that $\forall yP(y)$. The other direction uses similar tricks. We've flooded Asaf's ping box enough.

Answer (score 3):

I 'll just copy my proof from 
http://forums.philosophyforums.com/threads/lpl-exercise-and-60616.html

```
2  | |__________ ~Ex(Px -> VyPy)   New Subproof for ~ Introduction
3  | | |________ Pa                New Subproof for -> Introduction
4  | | | |_____b                   variable for Universal Introduction
5  | | | | |____ ~Pb               New Subproof for ~ Introduction
6  | | | | | |__ Pb                New Subproof for -> Introduction
7  | | | | | |   _|_               5,6 _|_ Introduction
8  | | | | | |   VyPy              7 _|_ Elimination
.  | | | | | <-------------------- end subpproof
9  | | | | |     Pb -> VyPy        6-8 -> Introduction
10 | | | | |     Ex(Px -> VyPy)    9 Existentional Introduction
11 | | | | |     _|_               2,10 _|_ Introduction
.. | | | | <---------------------- end subpproof
12 | | | |       ~~Pb              5-11 ~ Introduction
13 | | | |       Pb                12 ~~ Elimination
.. | | | <------------------------ end subpproof
14 | | |         VyPy              4-13 Universal Introduction
.. | | <-------------------------- end subpproof
15 | |           Pa -> VyPy        3-14 -> Introduction
16 | |           Ex(Px -> VyPy)    15 Existentional Introduction
17 | |          _|_                2,16 _|_ Introduction
.. | <---------------------------- end subpproof
18 |            ~~Ex(Px -> VyPy)   2-17 ~ Introduction
19 |            Ex(Px -> VyPy)     18 ~~ Elimination
```

This is the shortest I managed, I don't think a shorter proof using the standard introduction and elimination rules exist

Answer (score 1):

Here we can find a discussion of the [Drinker paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox).

We can prove it in *Hilbert-style* using the axiom system of Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd - 2001)).

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323029/how-to-show-that-vdash-forall-x-beta-to-alpha-leftrightarrow-exists-x) you can find a proof of theorem (Q3A) [see **Example 8**, page 130] :

> $\vdash(∀x \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \leftrightarrow ∃x(\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

From axiom 2 : $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha[x/t]$, where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$, with $P(x)$ as $\alpha$ and $y$ as $t$, we have :

> $\vdash \forall x P(x) \rightarrow P(y)$.

Thus we have :

> $\forall x P(x) \vdash P(y)$

and applying the **Generalization Theorem**  [page 117] :

> > $\forall x P(x) \vdash \forall y P(y)$.

Finally, by **Deduction Theorem** [page 118], we conclude :

> $\vdash (\forall x P(x) \rightarrow \forall y P(y))$.

Now we can apply the above theorem (Q3A), with $\forall y P(y)$ as $\alpha$ and $P(x)$ as $\beta$, where clearly, $x$ is not *free* in $\alpha$, to conclude :

> > > $\vdash \exists x (P(x) \rightarrow \forall y P(y))$.