# Name of rule for negating quantifiers

Tags: logic, terminology, quantifiers

A lot of rules of logic have accepted names:

- $\neg (P\lor Q)\iff(\neg P)\land(\neg Q)$ and $\neg(P\land Q)\iff(\neg P)\lor(\neg Q)$ are called "De Morgan's rules" (or "laws").
- $(P\lor Q)\land R\iff(P\land Q)\lor(P\land R)$ is called "distributivity."
- $(P\to Q)\iff(\neg Q\to\neg P)$ is called "transposition" or "replace with the contrapositive."

But what about the rules for manipulating quantifiers?

- $\neg(\forall x:P(x))\iff\exists x:\neg P(x)$
- $\neg(\exists x:P(x))\iff\forall x:\neg P(x)$

Do these rules have accepted names in English?

In [Negating statements with quantifiers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1990157/negating-statements-with-quantifiers), @Bram28 calls it the "dagger rule," but a quick Google search didn't turn up any great textual support for this name.

In [Why negating universal quantifier gives existential quantifier?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657931/why-negating-universal-quantifier-gives-existential-quantifier) it's opined that it's appropriate to call this rule **an axiom** of formal logic, but what I want to know is, "What axiom is it?" :)

In [A proof of $(\forall x P(x)) \to A) \Rightarrow \exists x (P(x) \to A)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577767/a-proof-of-forall-x-px-to-a-rightarrow-exists-x-px-to-a) the questioner uses it in a formal proof under the name of "A Known Identity," which is just beautiful. :)

I'm looking for a name so I can use it in a blog post, where I would first introduce the rule and say "This is called the Rule of Foo," and then farther down, I would say "Now we apply the Rule of Foo to transform this statement into..."

Comment: I would call these "de Morgan's laws for quantifiers": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Extension_to_predicate_and_modal_logic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operators $\forall$ and $\exists$ are so-called duals of each other, which for logic means that each is equivalent to the negation of the other applied to the negated subformula: $Q \phi \iff \neg Q^\delta \neg \phi$. The equivalence is hence commonly called "**duality** (of quantifiers)".
Note that the same duality property applies to the pair of connectives $\land, \lor$: $\ \phi C \psi \iff \neg(\neg \phi C^\delta \neg \psi)$;  so sometimes these rules are also subsumed under "**de Morgan's laws** (for quantifiers)".

Comment: I went with "De Morgan's laws for quantifiers." :)