# Questions about Quantifier Proofs with No Premise in Fitch

Tags: logic

I am currently a Philosophy student taking a logic course and I am quite confused about how I can go about tackling this following proof without a premise. I have been able to deal with all the practice proofs so far but this one has me stuck.

$$\exists x\,(P(x) \to \forall y\,P(y))$$

I have tried to solve this problem by reductio ad absurdum, but I have made little progress. Should I instead start by assuming $P(x)$, proving that it leads to $\forall y \, P(y)$, and then introducing the existential quantifier?

Comment: This is the famous [Drinker's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox), see ref for some ideas. It's most easy to prove in natural deduction systems...

Comment: @mohottnad ah! thank you so much.

Comment: Intuitively,  this says either the proposition is true for every element or there is a counter-example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're already several posts in this site about the proof of this seeming paradox in natural deduction systems, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412387/why-is-this-true-exists-xpx-rightarrow-forall-y-py) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/807092/proof-of-drinker-paradox/807558#807558), for instance.

In case you're interested in a proof for Hilbert system you can refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4331400/%e2%8a%a2%e2%88%83%e2%9f%b9%e2%88%80-using-hilbert-style-proof), it's much more cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest the following considerations   more as a topic for some discussion, then as an answer, but I hope it works as simple mathematics, not as philosophy. It's too long for a comment, but nowhere else to write. I am using formal statement from [Drinker_paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinker_paradox)
$$\exists x\in P.\,(D(x) \to \forall y\in P.\,D(y))$$
$$\exists x\in P.\,D(x)\lor \exists x\in P.\neg(\forall y\in P.\,D(y))$$
$$\exists x\in P.\,D(x)\lor \exists x\in P.(\exists y\in P.\,\neg D(y))$$
Now assuming $D$ is not dependent on $x$, then second member in disjunction is
only $\exists y\in P.\,\neg D(y)$ i.e. $\exists x\in P.\,\neg D(x)$, so we have
$$\exists x\in P.\,D(x)\lor \exists x\in P.\neg D(x)$$
$$\exists x\in P.\,(D(x)\lor \neg D(x))$$
Of course I used some properties of quantifiers and wait, that somebody brings more clearness, if needed.