# Hilbert system (with inference rule of modus ponens), show $\vdash \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

We're in first-order logic, using the Hilbert system (with inference rule of modus ponens), and the problem is to show $\vdash \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$.

We just learned about this stuff, so I'm really not sure where to begin. I believe we should create a sequence of deductions from $\exists x Px$ in order to arrive to the "proof of" $\forall x Px$. And we can use the following "axioms" along with modus ponens in order to arrive there:

- Tautologies
- $\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \alpha_t^x$, where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$.
- $\forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)\rightarrow(\forall x \alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta)$
- $\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \alpha$, where $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$

And if the language includes equality,

- $x=x$
- $x=y \rightarrow (\alpha \rightarrow \alpha')$, where $\alpha$ is atomic and $\alpha'$ is obtained from $\alpha$ by replacing $x$ in zero or more places by $y$.

Comment: Do you mean $\exists x(Px\rightarrow \forall yPy)$?

Comment: No, it is written with just $x$ in my book problem.

Comment: I just think it's strange to quantify twice over $x$ is all.

Comment: Anyway, an intuitive "proof" goes like this: either $\forall xPx$, in which case the sentence $Px\rightarrow \forall xPx$ is a tautology. Otherwise, there is at least one $x$ such that $\lnot Px$. If you chose such an $x$ from the $\exists x$-part, the sentence is of the form "false $\to$ false", which is also a tautology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323029/how-to-show-that-vdash-forall-x-beta-to-alpha-leftrightarrow-exists-x) you can find a proof of :

> $\vdash (∀xβ→α)↔∃x(β→α)$, if $x$ is not free in $\alpha$.

The proof uses the axioms you have listed.

In the above theorem we replace $\beta$ with $Px$ and $\alpha$ with $\forall xPx$. Clearly, $x$ is not free in $\forall xPx$: thus, the proviso of the theorem applies :

> $(∀xPx→∀xPx)↔∃x(Px→∀xPx)$.

The LHS is a *tautology*; thus, by *modus ponens* :

> > $\vdash ∃x(Px→∀xPx)$.

---

We can prove it directly with the above axioms and rules (see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122384520) (2nd - 2001)) :

*(1)* $\lnot Px \vdash Px \rightarrow \forall x Px$ --- by $\vDash_{TAUT} \lnot \phi \rightarrow (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$

*(2)* $\lnot Px \vdash \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ --- from (1) by the "derived rule" : $\varphi_t^x \rightarrow \exists x \varphi$ [provable from Ax.2] and *modus ponens*

*(3)* $\vdash \lnot Px \rightarrow \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ --- from (2) by *Deduction Theorem*

*(4)* $\lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px) \vdash \lnot Px \rightarrow \lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ --- by $\vDash_{TAUT} \phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi)$

*(5)* $\lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px) \vdash Px$ --- from (3) and (4) by $\vDash_{TAUT} (\lnot \phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi) \rightarrow ((\lnot \phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \phi)$

*(6)* $\lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px) \vdash \forall x Px$ --- from (5) by **GENERALIZATION THEOREM** [page 117] : $x$ is not free in the assumption

*(7)* $\lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px) \vdash Px \rightarrow \forall x Px$ --- from (6) by $\vDash_{TAUT} \phi \rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \phi)$

*(8)* $\lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px) \vdash \exists x(Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ --- From (7) by the "derived rule" of (2) and *modus ponens*

*(9)* $\vdash \lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px) \rightarrow \exists x(Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ --- from (9) by *Deduction Theorem*

*(10)* $\vdash \lnot \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px) \rightarrow \lnot \exists x(Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ --- by $\vDash_{TAUT} \phi \rightarrow \phi$

> *(11)* $\vdash \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ --- from (9) and (10) by $\vDash_{TAUT} (\lnot \phi \rightarrow \lnot \psi) \rightarrow ((\lnot \phi \rightarrow \psi) \rightarrow \phi)$

Comment: Wait you showed $\neg Px \vdash \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$ in line 3. Then you showed $\neg Px$ in line 4. Isn't this enough to show $\vdash \exists x (Px \rightarrow \forall x Px)$?

Comment: @Bobby Lee - NO - In line (3) we have $¬Px \vdash ∃x(Px→∀Px)$ but in line (4) we have $¬∃x(Px→∀Px)⊢¬Px→¬∃x(Px→∀Px)$ ...

Comment: How does line 2 follow from modus ponens? We would need $Pt \rightarrow \forall x Px$.

Comment: Could you please explain how the derived rule is being used? I don't see how it's applicable here.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 - No, we do not need (the invalid) $Pt→∀xPx$; I've used the valid $φ→∃xφ$, where $φ$ is :  $Px→∀xPx$.

Comment: But we need to get $\phi_t^x$ in order to use MP to get $\exists x \phi$. That is, we need to instantiate $\phi$ with some constant that does not appear in $\phi$, correct? If so, I don't see how we do this here.

Comment: NO; $t$ is a *term* and not a constant and $x$ is a term; thus $\varphi^x_x$ is $\varphi$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was thinking of existential instantiation in Enderton. But what you're saying is something different Thank you!