# How do you bring quantifiers to the front of a formula?

Tags: first-order-logic

I've recently seen

\begin{align}
F_1 &= \forall x p(x) \rightarrow \forall x q(x)\\
F_2 &= \forall x_2 \exists x_1 (p(x_1) \rightarrow q(x_2))\\
F_1 &= F_2
\end{align}

Why is that the case?

Can you read the first part of the equation as

> If p is true for all x, then q is true for all x.

? Why isn't it $F_3 = \forall x_1 \forall x_2 (p(x_1) \rightarrow q(x_2)) = F_1$?
Is there a model for $F_1$ which is not a model of $F_3$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you. I didn't know that (English is not my mother tongue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Prenex normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form) :

> A formula of the predicate calculus is in *prenex normal form* if it is written as a string of quantifiers (referred to as the *prefix*) followed by a quantifier-free part (referred to as the *matrix*).
>
> > Every formula in classical logic is equivalent to a formula in prenex normal form.

See **Conversion to prenex form** for the rules to be applied for the conversion.

---

We have :

> $(α → ∀xβ) ↔ ∀x(α → β)$, provided that $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$..

Applying it to your $F_1$ we get :

> **(*)** --- $(∀xp(x) → ∀yq(y)) ↔ ∀y(∀xp(x) → q(y))$

because $y$ is not *free* in $∀xq(x)$.

Then we need :

> $(∀xβ → α) ↔ ∃x(β → α)$, provided that $x$ is not *free* in $\alpha$ [you can find the proof of it in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323029/how-to-show-that-vdash-forall-x-beta-to-alpha-leftrightarrow-exists-x)].

We have to apply it to **(*)** above to get :

> $∀y(∀xp(x) → q(y)) ↔ ∀y∃x(p(x) → q(y))$, which is your $F_2$,

due to the fact that $x$ is not *free* in $q(x)$.

---

---

We can use this "intuitive" argument to convince ourselves of the reason why in $∀y(∀xp(x) → q(y))$ the "inner" universal quantifier "switch" to an existential one when it is "moved outside".

Consider $∀y(∀xp(x) → q(y))$ and apply the *tautological equivalence* : $(p \to q) \leftrightarrow (\lnot p \lor q)$ to get :

> $∀y(\lnot ∀xp(x) \lor q(y))$.

But $\lnot \forall$ is equivalent to : $\exists \lnot$; thus we have :

> $∀y(∃x \lnot p(x) \lor q(y))$

and thus :

> $∀y∃x (\lnot p(x) \lor q(y))$,

due to the fact that $\exists$ "distribute" over $\lor$ and that $x$ is not free in $q(y)$.

Now "reverse" the *tautological equivalence* above and we finally have :

> > > $∀y∃x (p(x) \to q(y))$.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that $p(x)$ is true for some $x$'s and false for others, and similarly for $q(x)$.  Then $F_1$ is true, because the antecedent is false.  $F_3$ is false, because I can choose an $x_1$ that makes $p(x_1)$ true and an $x_2$ that makes $q(x_2)$ false.

Comment: What are the rules how I have to change the quantor when I bring it to the front?

Comment: I don't have a handy answer for you there.