# how to prove this logic equivalence relation in the predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

How can I prove this in the predicate logic?

$B \rightarrow \exists xA $ Eq $\exists x (B \rightarrow A)$

Comment: It depends on the details of the proof system. For an Hilbert's style proof, see the answer to this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323029/how-to-show-that-vdash-forall-x-beta-to-alpha-leftrightarrow-exists-x).

Comment: Are you given that $x$ isn't free in $B$?  If not, then the claimed result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrate $B\to \exists x\; A \;\vdash\; \exists x\;(B\to A)$, by *natural deduction*.
$$\begin{array}{ll}B\to \exists x\;A & \text{P1} \\ \begin{array}{|ll} B & \text{Assume} \\\hline \exists x\;A & \text{Implication Elimination} \\ {A\mid}^x_c & \text{Existential Elimination} \end{array}\\ B\to {A\mid}^x_c & \text{Implication Introduction} \\ \exists x\;( B\to A ) & \text{Existential Introduction} \\ \Box\end{array}$$

---

Left to do: demonstrate $\exists x\;(B\to A) \;\vdash\; (B\to \exists x\;A)$